# (Parity) How do I correct "columns families not opened"

Tags: parity, bug

> Starting Parity/v1.5.0-unstable-0c7b7fc-20161204/x86_64-macos/rustc1.13.0
>
> 2016-12-04 18:50:47 State DB configuration: fast
>
> 2016-12-04 18:50:47 Operating mode: active
>
> 2016-12-04 18:50:47 Configured for Frontier/Homestead using Ethash engine
>
> Client service error: Client(Database("Invalid argument: You have to open all column families. Column families not opened: col5, col4, col3, col2, col1, col0"))

Comment: Delete all /parity/cache files and it should resume syncing from where it had stopped.

Comment: @MM_MarioMichel where are those cache files now with Openethereum?

Answer (score 4):

The cause of this is probably a corrupt database, itself caused by Parity having previously been shutdown in an ungraceful manner.

The error you're seeing is covered by issue [#2201](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/2201), but was fixed in [#3020](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/pull/3020). I'm struggling to see which version the fix went into, but presumably not `v1.5.0-unstable`, which is what you're running.

The recommendation in the notes to #2201 is to delete your blockchain data and re-sync from scratch.

Comment: Client service error: 
Client(Database("IO error: lock /Users/--------/.parity/906a34e69aec8c0d/v5.3-sec-overlayrecent/db/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable"))

Comment: Is Parity still running in the background? On the terminal, try `ps faux | grep parity`. Failing that, you could check which process has the lock using something like `lsof | grep 906a34e69aec8c0d`. When you find which process is holding the lock, kill it with `kill <process_id>`.

Comment: yes parity is still running in the background from the macos installer, i've tried

Comment: tried 
$ kill parity_906a34e69aec8c0d
-bash: kill: parity_906a34e69aec8c0d: arguments must be process or job IDs

next?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks since re sync from scratch now takes 2 years in the case of a full archive even when using cutting edge cpu for single thread performance, how to just reset the database to the block before it was broken?

Answer (score 4):

This is often caused by a corrupted database and can be solved by resetting it completely with:

```
parity db kill
```

This wipes the chain and the state and causes a full resync, but enables you to use parity again.

Comment: This worked great. takes a while to resync but it works.

Comment: Doesn't work for me for some reason: https://gist.github.com/Pzixel/c2607b035bcb0208a899111b426c23b4

Comment: I have manually removed everything from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Parity\Ethereum\chains` and it helped.

Comment: @Afr since re sync from scratch now takes 2 years in the case of a full archive even when using cutting edge cpu for single thread performance, how to just reset the database to the block before it was broken?

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this error when transferring a Parity node from one server to another.

My issue was that I (foolishly) `rsync`ed the chain data to the new server without having stopped the node. As such the database was corrupted.

Interestingly, if you are transferring a 'live' node, this may be the best way of doing things.

As you may know, by default rsync syncs new or modified files. I synced the files whilst the node was running. This took approximately 40 minutes. After it had completed (and would not load), I stopped the node and rsynced again. This synced only the modified files and took a matter of seconds. My new node was no longer corrupt, and my downtime was a matter of seconds.

Comment: What if the issue lies with a block which was corrupted years ago and unoticed?